# Generating a sine signal with time dependent frequency in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, numeric

I want to generate a sine signal `y(t)` with a time dependent frequency `f(t)` in Matlab.

I've already tried to realise this using the sine function of Matlab:

```
h = 0.0001;
npoints = 150/h;
for i = 1:1:npoints
   f(i) = 2 - 0.01*i*h;
   y(i) = 0.5*sin(2*3.1415*f(i)*i*h)+0.5;
end
```

where the frequency is decreasing with time and `h` is the time step width.

**My problem:**

The signal `y(t)` doesn't look I expected it to look like. There appears a bump in the amplitude at a distinct time (have a look at the plot below).

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens and how to generate this sine signal correctly?

Comment: how do you define negative frequencies here? If `0.01*i*h>2` you get a negative `f`.

Comment: `f` doesn't get negative here as `2 - 0.01*i*h` ist positive for all `i <= npoints`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about

```
y(i) = 0.5*real(exp(1i*2*pi*f(i)*i*h))+0.5;
```

You will get the plot below
[image]

If you just need a [`chirp`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/chirp.html) signal starting from 2Hz down to 0.5Hz, the following should do the job

```
f_start = 2; % start frequency
f_end = 0.5; % end frequency
endtime = 150; % seconds
timestep = 0.0001;
times = timestep:timestep:endtime;
y = chirp(times,f_start,endtime,f_end);
```

and if you plot it you get

```
figure(2);plot(times,y);
```

[image]

You can achieve the same manually using below

```
f_start = 2; % start frequency
f_end = 0.5; % end frequency
timestep = 0.0001;
T = 150;
rate_of_change = (f_start - f_end)/T;
times = timestep:timestep:T;
y = sin(2*pi*(f_start*times - times.^2*rate_of_change/2));
```

It might be useful to read the [following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp) Wikipedia page on Chirp signal.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but unfortunately, this doesn't work either.

Comment: I have uploaded the image I get. Is this not what you want? If not, it would help if you uploaded a picture of what exactly you want to get..

Comment: Well, in your plot the frequency also increases again after t = 100 s. I don't have a plot showing the signal I want, but mainly I want a sine shaped signal whose frequency continuously decreases.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At 100 you have `sin(2*pi*N)`, which is 0. Change f a little bit, say to `2.0123-...` and it goes to the top.

As for the general probably unexpected shape, consider what function you are using in the end (= substitute f back in the formula). You see that you have something of the form `y = ...sin(Ai-B*i^2)...`, which has a minimum at 100.

The easiest solution here is to simply offset frequency a little more, and use something like `f(i) = 3.1 - ...`, which has a minimum outside of your considered range.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I see the point that we get this unexpected shape because of the form of the function we get after substituting f back in the formula. Do you know how one could generate a sine signal (with the expected shape) whose frequency decreases in time? Unfortunately, I cannot change the offset. I need to generate a signal whose frequency varies in exactly this range.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there isn't actually a "bump in frequency", but at the 100 value on the x-axis the entire signal is **shifted by 180 degrees**. Bear in mind that the amplitude still reaches 0 and does not become smaller (e.g. from 0.25 to 0.75)

This is because the **i** value becomes so high that the value of f(i) **changes sign**.

Another indicator of this is that the frequency starts to increase again after the shift instead of gradually becoming even lower.

Why do you start off with the value of 2 in f(i)?

Sorry for asking for clarification here, but I cannot post it as a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Well, your explanation would be quite plausible if `f` would become negative. But `f` remains positive for all `i <= npoints`.

Comment: Hm, I guess it does then. I am just wondering what is causing the frequency to increase again then.